# RVM, Passenger, NGINX on top of existing Passenger/NGINX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, rvm

I previously had Passenger 2.2.13 install with NGINX 0.7.65 - I want to install rails 3 so I figured I'd go the RVM route. I followed instructions from http://blog.ninjahideout.com/posts/a-guide-to-a-nginx-passenger-and-rvm-server and am having issues because my previous install is in a different location and I think that is the one being used. When I make the changes to my nginx.conf file I get a 502 Bad Gateway on all of my apps..

Can anyone help me out with remove NGINX, Passenger, RVM, and re-installing fresh?

I am running OS X 10.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with using RVM and Passenger, passenger by default only has one path for ruby,once updated this worked fine. I've moved away from Passenger locally to avoid dealing with multiple environments.

Answer (score 0):

If the previous version was running ruby 1.8, I would do the following to have both apps running:

1. Install rvm
2. Replicate current ruby (ruby version, gems, etc) server configuration for rvm.
   This is step should include re-installing passenger gem for the new ruby.
3. Install ruby 1.9 using rvm and then follow this guide: http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/

I've done this using apache, and now everything is working ok.